# Making an array from a txt list

Tags: python

I want to strip the scores from the file and arrange them in an ordered list where I can print out the 1st, 2nd and 3rd place, here is my code:

```
scores = []
result_f = open("results.txt")
for line in result_f:
    (name, score) = line.split()
    scores.append = (float(score))
result_f.close()
print("The highest scores were: ")
print(score[0])
print(score[1])
print(score[2])
```

the console error python gives is:

File "C:\Python34\surfingscores.py", line 5, in 
    scores.append = (float(score))
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Answer (score 2):

`scores.append` is a function. Instead of using

```
scores.append = float(score)
```

try using

```
scores.append = float(score)
```

or an alternatively

```
scores[len(scores):] = float(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
scores.append(float(score))
```

Currently you are trying to **assign** a float value to the attribute `append` of the `scores` list, which is not what you want. The error is thrown because the `append` attribute of your `scores` list (which is the function for appending to that list) is read-only and thus explicitly protected from what your current code is doing.

```
>>> scores = []
>>> scores.append
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7f08964f9638>
```

Answer (score 1):

scores.append is a function/method of scores.

You need to make a function call.

```
scores.append(float(score))
```